# PHP - APC can't redefine class error

Tags: php, wordpress, centos, apc

This question has been asked previously but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I am trying to install PHP - APC on my server but whenever I enable it I get `"Can't re-declare class errors"`.

I have tried adding following settings to my php.ini but they didn't worked and I am still getting the error.

```
apc.include_once_override = 0
apc.canonicalize = 0
apc.stat = 0
```

The site is based on Wordpress and it uses W3 Total Cache plugin for caching. I also tried adding these settings to apc.ini of W3 Total Cache plugin but it also failed.

The version of APC is 3.1.13.

The server stack is:

```
Apache/2.2.25 (Unix)
PHP 5.4.21
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

The only solution that works is to disable APC but I need to keep it running.

Comment: What are the actual errors? It'll usually tell you **which** class.

Comment: @ceejayoz Its not for one class. I thought only one class was causing problem and created filter for it but then other classes started throwing errors. I think its most of the classes in wp-include directory.

Comment: @ceejayoz this is the actual error Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Walker_Page in /home/xxxxx/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 974 and after creating apc filters bunch of other files start throwing same errors.

Comment: What CentOS repos are you using?

Comment: @SibinGrasic CentOS-6 - Base, CentOS-6 - Extras and CentOS-6 - Updates. APC was installed by my VPS provider and I have checked it works fine on other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall php completely.

Add RHEL EPEL and REMI Repos

```
cd /tmp
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
```

Edit the **[remi]** portion of the file so that the enabled option is set to 1. This will enable the remi repository.

After that install php with dependancies:

```
yum install php php-cli php-common php-mysqlnd php-pecl-apc php-mcrypt php-imap php-mbstring php-gd php-xmlrpc
```